# While installing Go programming language trace.exe detected as virus by KAV

Tags: virus, antivirus, programming

When I tried to install Go programming language, Kaspersky AV in my system detected a path to file: `C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\trace.exe` as suspicious and triggered a virus alert.

Shall I consider this as a false positive alert or are there any threats associated with the detected object?

Comment: I would ask Kaspersky for support.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the installer from a trusted site via https connection then it's almost definitely a false positive. [This is a known problem.](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18699)

Comment: Yes it is.I downloaded the same from a trusted source and alert triggered after that. Anyway , considering it a s a false positive. Thanks for your answer mate.

Comment: "If you downloaded the installer from a trusted site via https connection then it's almost definitely [...]" - that's incorrect. File could be tampered on the server or the HTTPs certificate could be counterfeited. The only way to be 99% sure that the file wasn't tampered are digital signatures. And even those does not exclude the case where file was tampered on the developer machine, before signing.

Comment: @MarkSaelic that’s why I said “almost”. Digital signatures use precisely the same crypto as https: both have private keys that need to remain confidential and public keys, that could be tampered with in transfer. Both include certificate authorities that could be compromised. There's no end to paranoia, but I use threat modeling to cope: if your adversary is powerful enough to compromise CAs or hack distribution servers, then it's definitely capable of avoiding AV detection (it's almost trivial to do so).

Comment: It does not have to be an CA compromise, check this https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm for example. Also it's harder and harder to tell if site is trusted in the rise of new TLD's and cases like SourceForge. That's why we can relay only on digital signatures (which do not necessarily involve CA's).

Comment: @MarkSaelic Yeah, https could be man-in-the-middle'd, but only if your browser/OS have malicious certificates already installed. Otherwise the attempt to switch the certificates would result in huge red error messages in your browser. In most security questions I have an implicit assumption that the user's machine is not already compromised, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Everything is right. I just think that compromising the server or the PKI at some point is simpler than compromising GPG signature.

Comment: @MarkSaelic "That's why we can relay only on digital signatures" the TLS certificate *is* a digitally signed public key, we already rely on them. All digital signatures have a CA: to check the signature you need to have the public key of the signer. The place where you've got the key is the CA, you trust it not to switch the key you've requested. If you copied the public key from a webpage, then your CA is the whole stack that resulted in the characters appearing on the screen. Every point could be attacked, including the (hopefully) https that transmitted that webpage to you.

Comment: @MarkSaelic So unless you get your GPG keys via something more secure than https (face-to-face meeting, web of trust, etc.) then you do not achieve additional security. I agree that the https CAs are a bad solution, but I don't know what's better.

Answer (score 0):

Programs that inspects other programs are almost certainly under heavy watch by antivirus softwares, because inspection allows stealing data and altering process execution logic.

This include debuggers (e.g. your "trace.exe"), and cygwin1.dll (which use debugging system functions to implement the fork() system call, the memory-refilling part to be specific) among others.

However, major commercial software vendors are often whitelisted (e.g. MS Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check with https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload by uploading the file. If it is hash\signature based detection, you will be able to see intelligence from different vendors.

If the detection is behavior-based detection and you are sure that the executable behavior is expected, you can add the path to the scan exclusion list.